# Secure Erase SSD and HDD with ThinkPad Drive Erase Utility on ThinkPad Twist S230u

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, thinkpad, secure-erase

I have a ThinkPad Twist S230u with a 20GB M.2 SSD and a 320GB HDD that I cannot remember the passwords to. I haven't used this laptop in a while so I'm not concerned about whats on it but I would like to be able to use it again.

I've tried using the "ThinkPad Drive Erase Utility for Resetting the Cryptographic Key and Erasing the Solid State Drive". But I can't boot to it as I have to enter the passwords to both drives for it to boot. If I remove the drives I can boot to it but obviously I then can't do anything. I also for sure have a password on each drive as I've tried it with one drive at a time.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Where were the passwords your referring to set. Are these drive lock passwords set in the BIOS/UEFI menu or are they OS user passwords?

Comment: They were set in the BIOS, unfortunately you can't get to the BIOS without putting in the hard drive password.

Answer (score 1):

**With Linux you have hope**

windows wont let you do anything, however if you boot into a linux liveUSB stick, you have alot more options.

check out this guys successful experience unlocking their ssd, https://serverfault.com/a/733784

if you need to reset a password stored within cmos - [CmosPwd](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/CmosPwd)

a Linux liveUSB with everything you may need - [Rescatux](https://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=rescatux)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

**First,** I think there is some software online supports unlock Windows without PWD. I've seen a tech use this way to open Windows before, but failed to remember the name. Search this kind of tool in google. This way is easier, with data whole.

**Second,** this way is complex and will remove all data:

Move the hardware and connect it on anther PC(don't remove this PC hardware, or it wont boot). If correct, you will see this disk showing in Windows OS. Delete the disk data there, and download Backupper to create a "bootable media" and save it on the empty disk. And make a backup image or clone a working Windows to a USB.

Remove the USB and empty disk. Plugin disk to Thinkpad, set boot from "bootable media", plugin USB and reboot computer, and restore backup/clone image.

Done.

Still suggest you using 1st opt.

Comment: It's been awhile since I tried putting the hard drive in another computer, but if I remember correctly Windows wouldn't let me do anything to the hard drive since it is password protected. I couldn't format it or anything.